# Are ionic crystals, band insulators?

Tags: crystals, electronic-band-theory, insulators, ions

Ionic crystals are considered as electrical insulators. Is there a proof that they are insulators from the point of view of electronic band theory? In other words, is there a proof that ionic crystals do not have partially filled bands in their band structure?

Comment: Ionic conductivity is a thing, and has important technology applications (e.g. batteries). "Proving" every ionic crystal has an empty conduction band would be, well, difficult.

Comment: In the case of a crystal (solid) ions can not move so the conduction (if any) should take place by electrons. Also I edited my question: is there a proof that ionic crystals do not have partially filled bands in their band structure

Comment: Charged interstitials, charged vacancies, and diffusion of lattice ions are all contributors to ionic conduction. This applies to conductive ceramics as well. Google 'ionic conduction mechanism' to get a variety of sources to peruse.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this. My question is about electronic contribution.